# PHP, Wordpress, and Databases - Oh My

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am building a new WP site and am pulling data from a secondary database and displaying it within WP pages. I am currently using the PHP Insert plugin and have successfully been able to display data on my site by typing in the PHP code right into the text part of the page.

I'm new to PHP and the backend of WP sites so I'm trying to figure out if I can reference other PHP files from within my code snippet or do I have to put all the PHP code in one place.

If I can reference other PHP files, then where do I put them from within my Wordpress environment?

Any guidance you can offer for me to learn this would be greatly appreciated OR if you have a recommendation for another way to organize my new PHP code to run on WP pages instead of a plugin. THANK YOU!

Comment: You are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After [**doing more research**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/1011527) if you have a problem **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and provide [a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Read [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) a good question. Be sure to [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347937/1011527). *I wanted to +1 just for your title, but cannot.*

Comment: @JayBlanchard The question though is where **should** someone ask a question like this. It is a programming question but not theoretical (Computer Science) yet not down-and-dirty details either. It is, IMHO, actually a good question to ask **before** writing lots of PHP-inside-WP code as I have learned myself the hard way.

Comment: There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue which can be answered in a few paragraphs. I would suggest you find a development forum (perhaps [Quora](http://www.quora.com/Computer-Programming)?) to work out generalities. Then, when/if you have specific coding issues, come back to Stack Overflow and we'll be glad to help. This is how the question will be closed @manassehkatz There is nothing here asking where **should** the question be asked.

Comment: Thanks for your replies. I am going to try the working PHP in a custom wordpress template page and go from there.

Answer (score 1):

I have found that, except for the initial PHP code embedded in the WordPress page, it is easiest to maintain if all the other code resides elsewhere. WP sometimes does some funny things with loading pages due to showing parts of multiple posts on the home page, etc. so I have found it safest to use require_once() instead of require() or include(). I put the files in either a web accessible directory if they are designed to also run stand-alone, or in a non-web directory (generally preferred) if they should not be accessed except as part of your WP pages. Typically that would be `required_once('/home/whatever/private/xyz.php')` or `require_once('/var/private/xyz.php')` or something like that - the specifics will depend on whether you control the entire server or are working with what a shared hosting account gives you access to use. In some cases I distill it down to just a few parameters and the rest elsewhere - e.g.:

```
<?php
$id = 10;
$source = 'abc';
require_once('/home/whatever/private/xyz.php');
```

and let xyz.php do the rest as if it were running standalone with a couple of parameters passed in. The specifics will vary, but I've done it many times successfully.